# Zero'ing an array before adding an entry

Tags: c, compound-literals

Does the following zero out a list and then add the first entry? Or does it just add the first entry to `handlers`?

```
 Logger = (struct logger) {.level=INFO, .format=DEFAULT_FORMAT, .num_handlers=1, .handlers[0]=stdout};
```

For example, does this do:

```
Logger.handlers = {0};
Logger.handlers[0] = stdout;
```

Or is there no clearing involved?

Comment: If `.handlers[]` has more than one element, then `.handlers[0]=stdout` and all other elements are initialized zero by default. See: [C11 Standard § 6.7.9 Initialization (p21)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Could you post that as an answer? Because there's another answer that says the opposite. Also, note that this is a compound literal, not a variable initialization. But it inherits the semantics.

Comment: @Barmar sure, give me a second and I'll write it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, does this do:
>
> ```
> Logger.handlers = {0};
> Logger.handlers[0] = stdout;
> ```

*Answer: Yes (but not specifically in that order)*

There are three standard sections (actually 4 if you take the section that specifically makes the following two applicable to "aggregate objects" (struct and arrays)) under the section [C11 Standard § 6.7.9 - Initialization](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html). Your case asks "What happens to the other elements of `Logger.handlers` if only `Logger.handlers[0] = stdout;` is provided a value during initialization?"

To answer that question, you need to look at [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p19)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p19) and [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p21)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

The first specifies how initialization of structs occurs in "list order" and that `"all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."` So if you provide fewer than all values to fully initialize a subobject, those not provided a value are initialized as if they have static storage duration. (objects with static storage duration, not explicitly initialized, are initialized to zero (or `NULL`, as appropriate for type), See: [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p10)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10))

Paragraph 21 specifically covers your case where fewer initializers are provided within a brace enclosed list -- `"all subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration."` [§ 6.7.9 Initialization (p21)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p21)

So putting it altogether, what actually happens for the initialization of `Logger.handlers` is the first element is initialized to `stdout` and that all other elements are initialized NULL (since `stdout` is a pointer of type `FILE*`). So what you would actually have is:

```
Logger.handlers[CONST] = { stdout, NULL, NULL, ... };
```

Look things over (read all of [§ 6.7.9](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html)), and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks for this. Jeez the spec reads like its geared towards machines and has such an alien syntax...

Comment: There are a couple of section that leave you scratching your head. But you get used to them in time. One of the "less-articulately" worded sections has to do with the Strict Aliasing rule, [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) .... good luck with that one ... `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The latter `Logger.handlers[0] = stdout;`.  This is why the API has a .num_handlers field to tell called code know how many of the handlers are valid.

Comment: @Allen -- well, I wrote that code, so I'm not so sure you can trust it. The `.num_handlers` was added to make cleanup easier.

Comment: The other option is for the handlers to end the list with a magic value (i.e. NULL) .  Similar to how string is terminated by '\0' or could be struct with a char * and len.